# Spherical coordinates for cylindric domain...

Tags: calculus

Using spherical coordinates, I must describe domain inside cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$, under cone $z=\sqrt{3*(x^2+y^2)}$ and above plane $z=0$.

Easy enough using cylindical coordinates, but spherical?

Projecting in $z$, intuitively, I would say $0\le\theta\le2\pi$ and $0\le\phi\le\pi/2$.

For $z$ :

$$z=\sqrt{3*(x^2+y^2)}$$
$$p*\cos{\phi}=\sqrt{3*(p^2\sin^2{\phi}\cos^2{\theta}+p^2\sin^2{\phi}\sin^2{\theta})}$$
$$p*\cos{\phi}=\sqrt{3*(p^2\sin^2{\phi}(\cos^2{\theta}+\sin^2{\theta}))}$$
$$p*\cos{\phi}=\sqrt{3*p^2\sin^2{\phi}}$$
$$p*\cos{\phi}=\sqrt{3}p\sin{\phi}$$

FAIL.

How would I go about finding $p$ here?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are doing some integal, so about the borders
yes $0\le\theta\le2\pi$ but what you wrote is for $\phi$ (angle between p and z axis, p is radius i guess) you get $tan\phi=1/sqrt{3}$ or $\phi=\pi/6$ that mean $\pi/6\le\phi\le\pi/2$  try drawing picture, cone has bottom in (0,0,0), and finaly lets find out about p. p goes from 0 to cilinder, and as you wrote for cilinder we have $x^2+y^2=1$ or in spherical $p^2\sin^2{\phi}=1$ for our $\phi$ sinus is positive (p is always positive) so we can take square root and we get $p=\frac{1}{\sin{\phi}}$

so finaly
$0\le p\le \frac{1}{\sin{\phi}} $

that should be it :)